# When using Wordpress plugins with login for front-end users, will all plugins use the same user implementation?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I can't seem to find the answer to this online.

I don't have much experience with Wordpress but I need to build a site using a few plugins. They all offer the ability for users to register and login, and I need to know if they will all use the same user implementation (i.e. the native Wordpress one), so that when a user registers/logs in once they will get access to all of the plugins' features and be logged into all of them.

The plugins specifically are:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/faq/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/camptix/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/private-messages-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

First and third one seems to use WP Login. In second one users seems to use formula to order tickets so they will probably have to fill all fields every order, but still logged as your WP users. Second plug-in using external website to finalise ordering so your user will have to log in somewhere else.

In my opinion for example thanks to first plugin you will be able to control access to second one and your users will not have to register twice to use third one.

Comment: Thanks! Could I ask what makes you think the first and third ones use WP Login?

Comment: Most of all the idea of plugins do not require additional logging formula. In third one there will be probably created sth like another sql table for messages connected with registered users. In first there will be one more level of access i suppose connected with registered users as well. Those are my assumptions but this is how i would have done it and this is how 95% of that kind plugins work